# SOQL queries for the Files (owned / shared / following / libraries)

Tags: soql, lightning-aura-components, community, files

This 'Files List' component in Communities is pretty nice.  But I would like to create a modified version.

[Content Data Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content)

Could anyone help with the queries or filter criteria?  Ill be working on them also.  Ill post later as I get them, and hopefully replicate this component with the ability to customize it.

**The queries**

1. File Owned by Me
2. Files Shared with Me
3. Recent Files (Query 1, then sort by date, and take top 5?)
4. Files Im Following
5. List of Libraries I can access
6. Files within a Library

Im guessing #1 is similar to (Select Id, Title, FileExtension, CreatedDate From ContentDocument).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These queries will involve different tables.  I'll provide general information in this reply, but please let me know if you need additional assistance.

**File Owned by Me**

Query [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm?search_text=contentdocument) `where owner= <running user id>`

**Files Shared with Me**

Query [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm?search_text=contentdocumentlink) `where LinkedEntityId = <running user id> and ShareType != 'I'`

You want to exclude "I" ShareType because that would represent the user is the owner

**Recent Files (Query 1, then sort by date, and take top 5?)**

Query [RecentlyViewed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm) `where id starts with '069'`

**Files Im Following**

Query [EntitySubscription](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm) `where the parentId starts with '069'`

**List of Libraries I can access**

Query [ContentWorkspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm)

**Files within a Library**

Query [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm?search_text=contentdocumentlink) `where LinkedEntityId in (<set of workspaceIds from querying ContentWorkspace)`

Comment: I had a couple of them, but your conditionals also helped(excluding 'I' type).   Linking to the APIs is great as well for anyone that follows down the road.  I had never come across RecentlyViewed or EntitySubscription. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First : Query on ContentWorkspace
SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM ContentWorkspace

To Get all : SELECT Title,Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc)

and then Add the Name
SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM ContentWorkspace where Name ='Test Documents'